# C# различие List<T> и Collection<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics

В чем различие между List и Collection. Где и при каких условиях будет рациональнее использовать тот или другой тип?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Разница в том, что в `Collection<T>` есть ряд виртуальных методов (`InsertItem`, `RemoveItem`, `SetItem`, `ClearItems`), которые вы можете переопределить в классе-наследнике по своему усмотрению, и тем самым задать этим наследникам своё поведение при вставке, удалении или очистке элементов. 
При этом класс `List<T>` в большей степени сосредотачивается на быстродействии при выполнении операций вставки/удаления/очистки, нежели на предоставлении пользователю средств расширяемости в классах-наследниках (виртуальных членов у него нет вовсе).

MSDN нам авторитетно заявляет, что

> Provides the base class for a generic collection

Иными словами, класс `Collection<T>` в первую очередь предназначен для создания на его базе собственных обобщённых коллекций, тогда как `List<T>` "для работы"

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Кратко и по делу.